# Show checkbox in table in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm wondering how to enable checkbox in table header and table data of Bootstrap 3. Here is what I did in my code:( modified from Bootstrap example)

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
     <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                             <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox
                             </label>
                        </div>           
                    </th>
                    <th>用户id</th>
                    <th>姓名</th>
                    <th>电邮</th>
                    <th>组别</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                     <tr>
                         <td>
                             <div class="checkbox">
                                 <label>
                                     <input type="checkbox">
                                 </label>
                             </div>                                                               
                         </td>
                         <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                         <td>Win 95+</td>
                         <td> 4</td>
                         <td>X</td>
                    </tr>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As you see, the checkbox in header is now shown. And the checkbox in table data is not enabled (not clickable). Does anybody have example code to implement checkbox function?

Comment: can you share it on jsfiddle with full code

Comment: I solved it by using third party solution.